# How is the C++ synthesized move constructor affected by volatile and virtual members?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, move-constructor

Look at the following code:

```
struct node
{

  node();
  //node(const node&);    //#1
  //node(node&&);         //#2

  virtual                 //#3
  ~node ();

  node*
  volatile                //#4
  next;

};

int main()
{

  node m(node());         //#5
  node n=node();          //#6
}
```

When compiled with gcc-4.6.1 it produces the following error:

```
g++ -g --std=c++0x   -c -o node.o node.cc
node.cc: In constructor node::node(node&&):
node.cc:3:8: error: expression node::next has side-effects
node.cc: In function int main():
node.cc:18:14: note: synthesized method node::node(node&&) first required here
```

As I understand the compiler fails to create default move or copy constructor on line #6, if I uncomment either line #1 or #2 it compiles fine, that is clear. The code compiles fine without c++0x option, so the error is related to default move constructor.

However, what in the node class prevents default move constructor to be created? If I comment any of the lines #3 or #4 (i.e. make the destructor non-virtual or make data member non-volatile) it compiles again, so is it the combination of these two makes it not to compile?

Another puzzle, line #5 does not cause an compilation error, what is different from line #6? 
Is it all specific for gcc? or gcc-4.6.1?

Comment: You forgot `main`'s return type there skippy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `[C++11: 12.8/9]:` **If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if**
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - **`X` does not have a user-declared destructor**, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
>
> [ *Note:* When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that otherwise
>   would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor. —end note ]

That's why your #3 is breaking the synthesis.

In addition, [it's far from clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407737/are-volatile-data-members-trivially-copyable) that [volatile types (including your `node* volatile`) are trivially copyable](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3159.html#496); it could be concluded that [it is implementation-defined whether they are or not](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.std.c++/5cWxmw71ktI) and, in your case, it seems that they are not.

At the very least, [GCC made it stop working quite deliberately](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48118) in v4.7, with a proposal to backport into v4.6.1 that I can only presume went ahead...

So, given the following:

> `[C++11: 12.8/11]:` An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public member of its class. **A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if `X` has**:
>
> - a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding constructor and `X` is a union-like class,
>     a non-static data member of class type `M` (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to `M`’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
> - a direct or virtual base class `B` that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to `B`’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
> - any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member of a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
> - for the copy constructor, a non-static data member of rvalue reference type, or
> - **for the move constructor, a non-static data member** or direct or virtual base class **with a type that does not have a move constructor and is not trivially copyable**.

... that's why your #4 is breaking the synthesis too, independently of #3.

As for #5, that's not actually a declaration of a `node` at all, but a declaration for a function called `m` — that's why it's not reproducing the symptoms related to construction of a `node` (this is known as the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)).

Comment: Thanks, you made it very clear.  What still puzzles me, is that this code works fine:

Comment: What still puzzles me, is that this code works fine:            struct node { ~node(); node* volatile next; };                       and this also: struct node { virtual ~node(); node* next; };        so gcc-4.6.1 allows move ctors for volatile data members and for classes with destructors but somehow complains on the combination virtual dtor/volatile data member.

Comment: I wonder if the issue with volatile being trivially copyable is only the atomic semantics that some implementations want to give it. If so it seems to me that that change wouldn't be appropriate, because in ISO C++ volatile doesn't have atomic semantics

Comment: I would, if I had 4.7 :) I need to retain 4.6.1 and I don't want to have two gcc versions in parallel. But this sounds wrong, I agree.